# Firebase adding data into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I would like to add a new product to the allProducts array without deleting the existing product.

Here is the database.
[image]

And the code. This solution always overwrite the existing product.
[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an item to an existing array, you can:

- Either load the document, get the existing array from that, add the item to it, and then write the entire array back to the database.
- Or you can use the `array-union` operator that is described in the documentation on [updating an item in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

You'll probably want to do the latter here.